# Проблема с nodeJS и регистрацией через mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

у меня возникла странная, как мне сейчас кажется, проблема. До этого с базами я не работал, поэтому прошу помощи у специалистов!

Я написал скрипты для регистрации, создал базу данных, для пользователей, и создал там столбцы, `id: auto, (username, email, password): VARCHAR(255)` и пару столбцов с датой. Реквесты post работают отлично, проблема только в том, что "(username, email, password)" создаются как null и не могу понять в чем собственно проблема, так как кодировка стоит UTF8.

Вот собственно скриншоты, так как код думаю нет смысла писать сюда.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а если в таком виде данные: `username=aaa&email=bbb&password=ccc`?

Comment: @Igor тоже не работало, так как я элементарно указал тип данных которые отправляю, `Text` а сервер принимает `Application/json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ был тривиальный, хотя искал я его очень долго!

В общем суть была такова, во первых я не правильно создал таблицу! Я как человек, который не работал ранее с базами данных, создал ее в ручную, написал кодом все параметры - все стало чуть лучше. Начало выдавать, что параметры которые я передаю `NULL`

Далее, я изменил тип запроса на `Application/json` - Хоть и сам указал в самом файле сервера, какие запросы он принимает :D

В общем именно так я решил свою проблему, Спасибо за внимание, может кому-то пригодится на будущее!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]